# Linq to SQL : Left joining a grouped set makes a Cross Apply/Outer Apply

Tags: linq-to-sql, c#-4.0, group-by, left-join

Basically I'm making a report type query where I am aggregating data from multiple tables and left joining it to a single table.

it looks a bit like this:

```
var docs = from x in DB.Docs
           group x by x.PersonId into g
           select new { 
                g.Key, 
                totalSent = g.Sum(x => x.SentDate.HasValue ? 1 : 0),
                lastSent = g.Max(x => x.SentDate)
                ...
           };

var summary = from x in DB.People
              from y in docs.Where(y => y.Key == x.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new {
                   x.Id,
                   x.Name,
                   y.totalSent,
                   y.lastSent
              }
```

I would expect that this created sql that left joined `DB.People` to the results of `docs` but instead I get some crazy `CROSS APPLY(( SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]) as [t1] OUTER APPLY ...` stuff.

I've tried every variant of the left join syntax I can think, I've even wrapped `docs` in another query, and I get the same thing.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you not getting the results you want?  `CROSS APPLY` might seem crazy but in my experience LINQ to SQL is often smarter than I am with SQL and I just let it do its thing...if the results are correct.

Comment: Results never come back... `OUTER APPLY` basically makes my by grouped set a table valued function for each row of `DB.People`. The query times out.

Answer (score 0):

```
from x in DB.People
from y in docs.Where(y => y.Key == x.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
```

The above will clearly generate cartesian results which are later filtered.

Perhaps you meant to join:

```
from x in DB.People
join y2 in docs on x.Id equals y2.Key into g
from y in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

---

How about this:

```
from x in DB.People
let g = x.Docs
select new
{
  x.Id,
  x.Name,
  totalSent = g.Sum(y => y.SentDate.HasValue ? 1 : 0),
  lastSent = g.Max(y => y.SentDate)
}
```

Comment: My version is a shortcut, if `docs` did not represent a grouped set, it would create a left join.

Comment: So you get the same sql with my approach?

Comment: yeah, both approaches get you the same sql. The second example won't work unfortunately as these are POCO objects built on top of a somewhat unwieldy database architecture with a direct L2S mapping, that I don't have time to change. Docs for example represents a rather interesting query against 3 tables.